# Keyboard layout switches when starting search in Activities menu

Tags: gnome, keyboard-layout

I have an issue with keyboard layout quickly switching when I start typing after opening Activities overview. Here what I do:

0. Having an Eng keyboard layout active,
1. I press Win/Super key to open Activities overview
2. Then, I quickly start typing search term (e.g. the name of the application `slack`)
3. A couple of seconds after, I see that the first letter is English, but the rest of them are in Russian, e.g. `sдфсл` (most of the time I notice it after typing 3-5 letters by having an empty search result)
4. Now I observe the Russian keyboard layout as active.

This behavior is not consistent but very frequent, which is super annoying. I cannot even reproduce it on purpose, even though I face this problem for about a year or so. I have 2 keyboard layouts (Eng/Ru). The active layout is global for every application, and such switching is unique only for the search in Activities - I suppose it's sort of memorizing the layout at some point when I work on my laptop, which is not expected.

Is it a known bug and does it have any workarounds?

Specs: Ubuntu 20.10, 64-bit, GNOME version 3.38.3, X11

I cannot easily find any information about my problem, so even if you provide helpful links I will be grateful. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps a possible workaround: you could disable or change the shortcut keys for switching language layouts in Settings - Keyboard Shortcut, "Switch to next/previous input source" under the section "Typing".

Comment: @vanadium I have it set by default to super+space/shift+super+space. Honestly, I don't think it's related to my problem as I don't even press space anytime during steps mentioned in Q. Still, I'm gonna try playing around it

Comment: I only suggested this as a possibility. You are the only one who can test if that could help.